# Warm-up nodejs application using forms authentication under IIS 7.5

Tags: node.js, forms, authentication, iis, warm-up

We are hosting a nodejs application using forms authentication under IIS 7.5. I have installed the application warmup module available for download and when not using forms authentication, it works fine -> node.exe gets loaded during warm-up phase.

Now when forms authentication is activated, the redirection to some logging page (outside of the nodejs application) prevents node.exe to be called and preloaded in the w3wp.exe iis process.

Any ideas how to force node.exe module to be loaded during warm-up phase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working by looking at https://peterheibrink.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/warm-up-script-for-form-based-authentication-fba-sharepoint-sites/